# cannot import name 'a' from 'tools'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I can run test_pkg1.py and test_pkg2.py
but when I run test.py
Error occurred at test_pkg1.py

Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'a' from 'tools' (unknown location)

```
root
├─ pkg1
│  ├─ tools
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  └─ a.py
│  ├─ __init__.py.py
│  └─ test_pkg1.py
├─ pkg2
│  ├─ tools
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  └─ b.py
│  ├─ __init__.py.py
│  └─ test_pkg2.py
├─ test.py
└─ d.py

test_pkg1.py 
   from tools import a  

test_pkg2.py
   from tools import b  

test.py 
   from pkg2 import test_pkg2
   from pkg1 import test_pkg1
```

Comment: This may because you don't have an `__init__.py` file in the same directory as `test.py`

Answer (score 0):

In Python, import paths are always relative to the directory where the main program is executed unless you explicitly use a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) by preceding the package name with a dot, which then makes the interpreter look for the package in the same directory as the module where the import is made:

**test_pkg1.py:**

```
from .tools import a
```

You also need to create an `__init__.py` file in the directory where the main program runs in order for that directory to be considered a package under which relative imports can be made.

Comment: But when I import with a dot,error occured when I run test_pgk1.py.   Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: I see. You also need to create an `__init__.py` file in the main directory. I've updated my answer accordingly.